# Confused about the reference type assignment

Tags: ios, swift, data-structures, linked-list

Following is a portion of a linked list implementation and I'm confused about the semantics:

```swift
class Node<T> {
    var value: T
    var next: Node?
    weak var previous: Node?
    
    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

struct LinkedList<T> {
    var head: Node<T>?
    var tail: Node<T>?
    
    init() { }
    
    // what this method actually does is unimportant, but it creates a linked list from a sequence
    func createChain<S>(of sequence: S) -> (head: Node<T>, tail: Node<T>)? where S: Sequence, S.Element == T {
        var iterator = sequence.makeIterator()
        guard let firstValue = iterator.next() else {
            return nil
        }
        var head: Node<T>
        var tail: Node<T>
        
        var currentNode = Node(value: firstValue)
        head = currentNode
        
        while let nextValue = iterator.next() {
            let newNode = Node(value: nextValue)
            currentNode.next = newNode
            newNode.previous = currentNode
            currentNode = newNode // ?
        }
        
        tail = currentNode
        return (head: head, tail: tail)
    }
}
```

Let's say if I were to create a linked list using above code:

```swift
let linkedList = LinkedList<Int>()
let sequence = [0, 1, 2]
let chain = linkedList.createChain(of: sequence)
```

On the first cycle of the `while` loop, the snapshot would be as follows:

```swift
while let nextValue = iterator.next() {
    let newNode = Node(value: nextValue) // newNode: previous = nil, next = nil, value = 1
    currentNode.next = newNode // currentNode: previous = nil, next = newNode, value = 0
    newNode.previous = currentNode // newNode: previous = currentNode, next = nil, value = 1
    currentNode = newNode // ?
}
```

When the final line is executed, I understand superficially that the new node has to replace the current node continuously to cycle through all the elements of the sequence, but I'm not exactly sure what's happening when `currentNode` sets `newNode`. It doesn't make sense that `newNode` overwrites `currentNode` since `currentNode`'s `next` has just been assigned with `newNode` and `newNode`'s `next` is nil.

If `newNode` is not overwriting `currentNode`, how does the content of `newNode` not affect `currentNode` in `currentNode = newNode`?

Comment: it's just mark currentNode is the `tail` of current list, then continously append to the `tail`. You can think variable name is a pointer, the memory of actual object is somewhere. After first loop round, the `newNode` pointer is disappeared but its memory is still accessible via `currentNode`.

Comment: how does `currentNode.next` from `currentNode.next = newNode` still stay intact even though `currentNode = newNode` happens afterwards?

Comment: because Node is class, reference type, so when you assign new value, it points to another address. you should research more about reference type and value type, pointer and object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are *reference types*.  This means that `currentNode` holds a reference to an instance of that `Node`.  When you assign a new instance to `currentNode`, you are changing the object that is referenced. As long as some other variable or property holds a reference to the previous instance, it will remain in memory.

This is why it is important that the first `Node` referred to be `currentNode` is assigned to `head`; If `head` didn't hold the reference then that `Node` would be released when a new `Node` was assigned to `currentNode`.  References to subsequent `Node`s are held by the `previous` and `next` properties, keeping them in memory too.

To illustrate I will show the sequence using fictitious memory addresses denoted by *0, *1 etc:

Before the `while` loop:

- `currentNode = Node*0(0,nil,nil)`
- `head = Node*0(0,nil,nil)`

Note that `currentNode` and `head` refer to the same memory addresses.

First time through the `while` loop:

- `currentNode = Node*0(0,nil,nil)`
- `newNode = Node*1(1,nil,nil)`
- `currentNode = Node*0(0,Node*1,nil)`
- `newNode = Node*1(0,nil,Node*0)`
- `currentNode = Node*1(nil,Node*0)`

Note that `currentNode` now references `Node*1`.  `head` is still referring to `Node*0` as is the `previous` value of `Node*1`

Next time through the `while` loop:

- `currentNode = Node*1(1,nil,Node*0)`
- `newNode = Node*2(2,nil,nil)`
- `currentNode = Node*1(0,Node*2,nil)`
- `newNode = Node*2(0,nil,Node*1)`
- `currentNode = Node*2(nil,Node*1)`

And so on

Finally, the implementation of `createChain` is a little odd; It returns a tuple of `(head,tail)` and it operates on an  empty `LinkedList`.

You can implement it as a static function that returns a `LinkedList` -

```
struct LinkedList<T> {
    var head: Node<T>
    var tail: Node<T>
    
    // what this method actually does is unimportant, but it creates a linked list from a sequence
    static func createChain<S>(of sequence: S) -> LinkedList<S.Element>? where S: Sequence, S.Element == T {
        var iterator = sequence.makeIterator()
        guard let firstValue = iterator.next() else {
            return nil
        }
        var head: Node<S.Element>
        var tail: Node<S.Element>
        
        var currentNode = Node(value: firstValue)
        head = currentNode
        
        while let nextValue = iterator.next() {
            let newNode = Node(value: nextValue)
            currentNode.next = newNode
            newNode.previous = currentNode
            currentNode = newNode // ?
        }
        
        tail = currentNode
        return LinkedList(head: head, tail: tail)
    }
}
```

Then you can create your linked list with

```
let sequence = [0, 1, 2]

let list = LinkedList.createChain(of: sequence)
```

Comment: At the end of the first time through the loop, `currentNode.next = newNode` modifies the memory of `head` as well, meaning it will have `head = Node*0(0,Node*1,nil)`.  But, when `currentNode = newNode` happens, why isn't the `head` modified?  In other words, why won't the head's memory be `head = Node*1(nil,Node*0)`?

Comment: Think of it this way, If I said `currentScore = 1; oldScore = currentScore; currentScore = 2` You wouldn't expect `oldScore` to suddenly be 2.  Same thing; `head` has a value of "Pointing to Node*0".  `currentNode = newNode` means that `currentNode` now has a value of "Pointint to Node*1". `head`s value remains unchanged

Comment: I see. So would it be correct to say that `head` changes in the case of `currentNode.next = newNode` because it's not modifying the memory address, but just the content? On the other hand, `currentNode = newNode` changes the entire memory address, therefore `head` is unaffected.

Comment: `head` doesn't change. The thing it is *pointing to* changes. Once you assign a new value to `currentNode` then it and `head` are pointing to different things.